# Not getting the Bundle value

Tags: android, bundle

Iam facing the problem while recieving the data through Bundle..

```
Intent toAudio = new Intent(TourDescription.this, Audio.class);

toAudio.putExtra("SIZE", arraypoi.size());

for(int i=0; i<arraypoi.size(); i++)
      toAudio.putExtra("POI"+i, arraypoi.get(i));
startActivity(toAudio);
```

In the recieving class I have,

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();

int size=data.getInt("SIZE");

for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    listOfPOI.add((PointOfIntrest) data.getParcelable("POI"+i));// Iam getting the exception //here..PointOfIntrest is the class name here..
```

can anyone help me with this ?

Thanks,
Keerthiraj

Comment: for loop in my recieving class is as follows

Comment: If you're getting an exception you should post a logcat

Answer (score 0):

If your for loop is not working then you should make **toAudio.putExtra("SIZE",arraypoi.size());** to **toAudio.putInt("SIZE", arraypoi.size());**.
Hope it will work.

Comment: Actually Iam getting the exception for,for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
   listOfPOI.add((PointOfInterest) data.getParcelable("POI"+i));

Comment: where listOfPOI is List<PointOfInterest> listOfPOI;

Comment: You make the changes what i have mentioned then we will see.ok? you can do changes.it is a small changes you can undo easily.